# Ant design charts, how to display data with duplicate name in column chart

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, antdv

I have an array of objects that looks like this

```
 [{type: 'apples', sales: 52},
  {type: 'apples', sales: 62},
  {type: 'apples', sales: 72}]
```

I want to build a column chart from [Ant Design Charts](https://charts.ant.design/demos/column/) with this data but instead of 3 columns, I have only one.
I don't see how to make it display each record separately.

Here is a code https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-wind-i06ul?file=/App.tsx

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should group the records by the actual feature that differentiates them (i.e - what is the difference between the first apples record and the second one? Are they from different dates, different shops, etc..). That's how aggregation works in general. You always sell apples, that shouldn't be used as an axis. Give more information about your actual context.

Comment: you can try the stacked column so on one column you can group many options. https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/column/stacked#basic

Answer (score 1):

just need to add:

isStack: true,

var config = {
data: data,
xField: "type",
yField: "sales",
**isStack: true,**
xAxis: {
label: {
autoHide: true,
autoRotate: false
}
}
};